# Why does this endless loop not use up my system resources?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, process

I did the following in BASH:

```
while true;do bash;done
```

I wrote this one liner, but I was not sure at first whether it:

- stays in the main shell and fathers as many subshells as it runs dry of memory or some other stuff.
- the main shell fathers a subshell, than this subshells fathers a subshell until this lineage runs dry of memory or some other stuff.

But, I suppose it is the second case, because once I run the one liner, I got shortly after my prompt back and I began to type exit and another exit and exit, exit, exit...and I still was not back in the main shell.

Now, since so many subshells have been opened and each one is a program, I thought each one should have its own PID.

So I did:

```
ps aux | grep bash
```

expecting to see a lot of processes with bash in their names.

However, nothing like this, there were only two bash shells.

How is it possible, I guess I have somewhere a very wrong idea of processes, shells, subshells and PIDs, but do not know where.

Comment: Does s.o. know how to make a shell spawn many shells in parallel or sequence?

Comment: The term you appear to be looking for is a "[fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)". Handle with care, as fork-bombing yourself is rarely much fun.

Comment: thank you, I was not aware  it has such a dramatic name

Comment: @sharkant f() { f() & f() &;};f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop starts one single interactive shell session in each iteration.

The interactive session gives you a prompt (since it's interactive).  Exiting it gives the control back to the loop, which starts another interactive shell.

This is why you don't get a massive amounts of `bash` processes at once, only two, the parent which runs the loop, and the child which gives you the new prompt.

---

The loop may also be written

```
while true; do bash; done
```

The `true` utility does not take an argument, it just returns a zero exit value which is interpreted as "true" by the shell.

---

If you had wanted an explosion of `bash` processes (a so called "fork-bomb"), you may have written

```
while true; do { bash & }; done
```

This would start an interactive `bash` session in each iteration of the loop, but as *background processes*.  Since the sessions are started as background processes, the loop will not wait for the latest `bash` process to finish before starting the next one.

You may have to reboot your system to recover from this.

This fork-bomb is more benign than what it could be, as it only starts *one* new process in each iteration. Others may well start processes in an exponential fashion.

Comment: This makes totally sense, at least visually, each iteration kicks me  out of the loop and when I type exit I get back in the loop just to get kicked out again. I heard the term but I do not really know what an "interactive shell" is, but if it was an "noninteractive shell" would it work to spawn a plethora of subshells?

Comment: @sharkant An interactive shell is a shell that you type commands into. A non-interactive shell is a shell that performs a task without having to prompt the user for input (like running a shell script).  Try replacing `bash` with `bash -c 'echo hello'` (which runs `bash` as a non-interactive shell) to see the difference. Press `Ctrl+C` (maybe a few times) to interrupt the loop if you test this.

Comment: @sharkant You still only get a total of two shells at a time though.  The non-interactive shell does what it's suppose to do and exits before the loop starts the next one.

Answer (score 6):

Your loop is starting an endless number of shells, but one after the other, not in parallel. The first time the loop runs, it runs `bash`, which starts a new shell and displays the prompt. The parent shell waits for that shell to exit; this happens when you type `exit`, exiting the child shell and returning to the parent shell, which goes round the loop again and runs `bash`, which starts a new shell and displays the prompt...

You can display your shell level by running

```
echo $SHLVL
```

You’ll see this number doesn’t change when you type successive `exit` commands.